# Writing my own asort and ksort function in php

Tags: php, sorting, ksort, asort

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how i would go about writing my own asort and ksort function please?

I'm still new to php...thank you!

Edit: This is what i would like to sort:

```
$employeeAges = array();
$employeeAges["Lisa"] = "28";
$employeeAges["Jack"] = "16";
$employeeAges["Ryan"] = "35";
$employeeAges["Rachel"] = "46";
$employeeAges["Grace"] = "34";

foreach( $employeeAges as $name => $age){
    echo "Name: $name, Age: $age <br />";
}
```

I'd want my_sort($employeeAges); to do exactly the same as asort but i have to write the function myself

Edit: This is homework...otherwise i'd simply use the functions, just need a push in the right direction, i dont expect the code. Thanks

Comment: Why?  Homework maybe?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? The native function are there to be used, and they are lot faster then code written in php.

Comment: Yeah homework...no idea why he'd ask us to do that! i dont expect the code just a push in the right direction :P

Comment: Google some search algorithms. Quick sort, merge sort and so on.

Comment: wumm, like i said i dont expect the code just a push in the right direction as everything i google is helpless.

Comment: What have you done so far?  This is homework, you should make an attempt and we can help you out with specific problems you encounter.

Comment: Sorting algorithms then probably were explained in class. Please narrow your question down to where you're stuck.

Comment: We haven't learned any sorting algorithms in class, he just throws us in the deep end. I'm stuck as to how i would sort the array, could i just use a bubble sort type algorithm...i'm going to edit the question to provide more info

Comment: Downvoting for lack of previous research efforts. You know you need to sort. So search for sorting algorithms. Anyway, you don't learn anything from your homework if we are going to give you the solution on a golden plate.:)

Comment: Dont want the solution, just to be pointed in the right direction, thought there would be a website that would explain php functions etc...all the ones i've visited aren't helpful

Comment: I used Google - https://phpcoderblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/php-some-sorting-algorithms-bubble-sort-selection-sort-counting-sort-quicksort-shellsort-heapsort/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your homework is specifically worded but if its that you can't use `asort` or `ksort` then you can do things like ...

```
function my_sort(&$my_array){
    arsort($my_array); // not using asort were using arsort
    $my_array = array_reverse($my_array,true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was along the lines of what i was looking for

Answer (score -1):

You'll likely need to use `natsort` and `sort` -- and you'll need to use some combination of `array_keys`, `array_values`, and `array_merge`

But when in doubt, [Read The Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)